# How can change link type of pdf links by itext7?

Tags: c#, itext7

I want edit to visible rectangle of links in file pdf:

If i use acrobat ,i can edit link type to "`Visible Rectangle`"

[image]

[image]

But with iText7 , How can change this value?

I try setting, but it not working:

```c#
string strPage = @"C:\test1.pdf";
string strPageNew = @"C:\result.pdf";
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(strPage);
using (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(strPageNew))
{
    using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer))
    {                    
        PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDoc.GetPage(1);
        var annotations = pdfPage.GetAnnotations();
        if (annotations != null)
        {
            foreach (PdfAnnotation a in annotations)
            {
                if (a.GetSubtype().Equals(PdfName.Link))
                {
                    PdfLinkAnnotation link = (PdfLinkAnnotation)a;
                    var action = link.GetAction();
                    if (action != null)
                    {
                        if (action.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.URI))
                        {
                            PdfString destination = action.GetAsString(PdfName.URI);
                            
                            link.SetFlag(4);
                            link.SetHighlightMode(PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_OUTLINE);
                            link.SetBorderStyle(PdfAnnotation.STYLE_SOLID);
                            link.SetColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.RED );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

reader.Close();
```

Comment: *"but it not working"* - What does that mean? Does it not compile? Or does it throw an error when run?

Comment: Please attach the source PDF to reproduce the problem

Comment: @mkl: it can't change "Link Type" to "Visible Rectangle" and Rectange of Link will not visible. it not occur error.

Comment: Please be aware that if the annotation has an appearance stream, a PDF viewer is required to show the appearance stream and ignore settings like the border style and color. So if the link annotation you manipulate has an appearance, you have to update or replace it to show your desired appearance, or you have to remove it so that the viewer creates an appearance according to the border properties you set.